# How approach storing user data in Firestore

Tags: database, firebase, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a bit confused about how should I store user data in Firestore. I found many examples of simple databases in it but none of them had all data connected with one user. For instance, I'm not sure if (or when) should I put user ID in the document index or field? As an example I can show what exactly my problem is because it's still rather simple:

I want to store users times with car on the track. So the user has many times on car + track pairs. My idea, for now, is to divide times into two collections, one for all times (because it will be used less frequently) and second for the user best times so:

*[(C)ollection, (D)ocument to show how I see it because maybe there is something wrong]*

> user_times(C) -> user(D) -> car_track(C) -> time(D)

doc with userId as index -> collection with e.g. ferrari_spa name -> document with random index and time details

and for the best times - each pair as root collection:

> car_track_best_time(C) -> user(d)

e.g. porsche_monza_best_time collection having documents with user ID as index and field with time. What do you think about it? Does it make any sense?

Comment: Hi Alan! What are the exact quries you want to perform?

Comment: What I'm sure I would need are two things - getting (always as user - his own data) list of best times in all cars on a specific track to show it rank (like e.g. on Spa my best time is in Ferrari, second is Porsche, etc.). The second thing is car place in all ranks like that so for example in Nissan I was fastest on two tracks, once second etc.

Both will use only best_times for car-track pairs but I want log also all times for future use. I'm not sure yet how exactly but for sure for statistics like progress in time.

Comment: So first you want to get user details, meaning you want to display the best times, no matter what car on a single circuit. Something similar with: `SELECT bestTimes FROM users WHERE circuit = specificTrack (no matter what care), right? And second, you want to get the best two times when used a Nissan car on specific two track, is that what you want? Is it for Android, iOS or web?

Comment: Not exactly, it's always for one user, so as a user I want to check only my records on the circuit and there is always only one record for every car-track pair. So if there are 12 cars, then on every circuit the user has up to 12 bestTimes. The second case is to get the info on how good certain car is for me, for example on how many tracks it is in top 3 records.

Comment: And it's for web, specifically with React.